# How do I programatically search for Wi-Fi access point using PAlib on the Nintendo DS

Tags: wifi, nintendo-ds, palib

I need a way to check for Wi-Fi routers/access points on my DS homebrew. I'm using PAlib.

Answer (score 2):

i used the code from ds_wifi_test (which comes with the original dswifi library) when i tried to implement this. Basically, access points are scanned internally when you invoke `Wifi_ScanMode()`. You can then have the number of AP identified with `Wifi_GetNumAP()` and retrieve the information for the ith access point with `Wifi_GetAPData(i,&data);`

```
nbitems=Wifi_GetNumAP();
Wifi_AccessPoint ap;

for (int i=0;i<nbitems; i++) {
   if(Wifi_GetAPData(i+scrolltop,&ap)==WIFI_RETURN_OK)
      do_whatever_with(&ap);
}
```

I'm not aware of any "helper" functions through the PALib in this regards. All the PALib seems to have is a few "wrappers" to ease common tasks once a WFC setting has been defined ([see day#20 tutorial](http://www.palib.info/wiki/doku.php?id=day20))

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd steer clear of PALib. It's built atop an outdated version of libnds, and isn't updated with the new version in the interests of backwards-compatibility. Instead, take the time to learn libnds, and reap the benefits of a well-maintained library that doesn't have dependencies of its own. The same code that sylvainulg wrote above will still work, as it is dependant on dswifi, not libnds or PALib.